# python сохранить файл doc в pdf

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как в python сохранить файл doc в pdf
на примере простого кода:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
doc = DocxTemplate("шаблон.docx")
context = { 'emitent' : 'ООО Ромашка', 'address1' : 'г. Москва, ул. Долгоруковская, д. 0', 'участник': 'ООО Участник', 'адрес_участника': 'г. Москва, ул. Полевая, д. 0', 'director': 'И.И. Иванов'}
doc.render(context)
doc.save("шаблон-final.docx")
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из решений - воспользоваться библиотекой `docx2pdf`

В вашем примере формат файла `docx` подходит для её работы, но если понадобится сконвертировать файл с форматом `doc`, то для этой задачи библиотека не подойдет.

Для установки пропишите в консоль следующую команду `pip install docx2pdf`

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
```

Comment: Добавил в код, но файл так и не поменялся на pdf

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx2pdf import convert

doc = DocxTemplate("/Users/turremail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон.docx")
context = { 'emitent' : 'ООО Ромашка', 'address1' : 'г. Москва, ул. Долгоруковская, д. 0', 'участник': 'ООО Участник', 'адрес_участника': 'г. Москва, ул. Полевая, д. 0', 'director': 'И.И. Иванов'}
doc.render(context)
doc.save("/Users/turremail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон-final.docx")

convert("/Users/turrÅemail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон-final.docx", "/Users/turremail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон-final.pdf")

Comment: @МихаилТаратенко в папке с проектом должен появиться файл с расширением .pdf, исходный файл остаётся неизменным

Comment: Павел, мне так и казалось что должен появиться, но почему-то не появился?! Выдаёт ошибку что нет прав на чтение файла исходного.

Comment: @МихаилТаратенко советую также не использовать абсолютные пути, они затрудняют поиск ошибок. Попробуйте заменить все пути вида "/Users/turremail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон-final.docx", на "шаблон-final.docx", в случае если .py скрипт находится в папке Phyton

Comment: @МихаилТаратенко также прошу прислать вывод из консоли при использовании данной библиотеки. В моём случае вывелось 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.96s/it]

Comment: /Users/turremail.ru/PycharmProjects/documets/venv/bin/python /Users/turremail.ru/PycharmProjects/documets/Doc_insert.py 
  0%|          | 0/1 [01:23<?, ?it/s]
{'input': '/Users/turrÅemail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон-final.docx', 'output': '/Users/turremail.ru/Desktop/Phyton/шаблон-final.pdf', 'result': 'error', 'error': 'Error: Сообщение не понято.'}

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Павел, видимо проблема в доступе к файлу.

Comment: Приложению Word не удалось открыть документ, так как пользователь не обладает достаточными правами
(шаблон-final.docx)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141225/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: Почему-то не могу писать сообщения в чате

Comment: @МихаилТаратенко вариантов не много, всё, что могу посоветовать
1) Попробуйте изменить всё-таки абсолютные пути на относительные
2) Измените права доступа к файлу.

Comment: Павел, спасибо огромное буду пробовать.

Comment: @МихаилТаратенко отлично, рад, что у вас получилось. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример использования comtypes , преобразования одного файла, имен входных и выходных файлов, заданных в качестве аргументов командной строки:

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```